# Wake on lan via my custom router

Tags: linux, networking, router, wake-on-lan

I want to use wake on lan via my custom router. Below image is my networking image. I could make connection from smart phone to raspi3 using google cloud platform and VPN (softether), and from raspi3 to Desktop PC **when the Desktop PC turns on**.

However, when the Desktop PC turns off, `eth1` is not assigned IP address. So I couldn't use wake on lan (couldn't send magic packet to Desktop PC with Python). Here is `ifconfig` output;

```bsh
sudo ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.20  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.16.1.255
        inet6 fe80::51dd:e5ef:c061:adb9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:df:31:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 158  bytes 26655 (26.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 168  bytes 42199 (41.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 04:ab:18:3b:af:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vpn_vpn_nic: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ebcc:65ba:a7f4:a21e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::5cab:14ff:fe17:ae3a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5e:ab:14:17:ae:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2  bytes 122 (122.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 5198 (5.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:8a:64:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Question1: How can I assign IP address to `eth1` when the device connecting `eth1` turns off?

Question2: Should I create virtual bridge to achieve this?

[image: network image]
UPDATE1:
I tried Philip's answer such like

```bsh
sudo arp -s 192.168.1.19 **:**:**:**:**:**
```

, however, output was

```bsh
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

No established network caused this? Should I create 192.168.1.0?

↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

After I added

```bsh
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1
```

in `/etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook`, I could pass `sudo arp -s 192.168.1.19 **:**:**:**:**:**`. But PC is still sleeping now... :(

Comment: why not use specialized wol tools? There are at least two of them: https://packages.debian.org/stable/etherwake , https://packages.debian.org/stable/wakeonlan . Also note than *on your PC* tools like NetworkManager can interfere with the correct card settings to enable to be woken up with WOL packets.

Comment: Thank you for telling me very useful wol tools. I use Python's socket library (such like [this code](https://github.com/bentasker/Wake-On-Lan-Python/blob/09c151b0c47db7373932f375b4187e2de2bd4e70/wol.py#L53)) to send magic packet. I'll use wol tools you told me later.

Comment: looking at wakeonlan (and a capture) I could "reimplement" it easily using xxd and socat from shell.

Comment: I sent magic packet by wakeonlan **:**:**:**:**:** in my raspi. But my PC didn't wake up...
Perhaps I may mistake PC's setting for wol. I'll check them.

Comment: WOL magic packet is sent to a MAC address, not to an IP address

Comment: Studying how `wakeonlan` sends it helps a lot: to broadcast (broadcast IP => broadcast MAC), thus not needing anything fancy, just standard UDP.

Comment: OK. I understood wake on lan maybe. Then, I tried wake on lan again, and almost wake on lan failed, but rarely succeeded. It's strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple Answer

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  The simple way to achieve this is that you don't need to assign it an IP address.  Send the WOL packet to your LAN's [broadcast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).  This is almost always the last address in the subnet.  So if your LAN is on `192.168.1.x` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0` the broadcast address will be `192.168.1.255`.

This will be sent to ALL machines on the LAN (all machines on the same subnet at least).  This won't matter!  The WOL "[magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet)" must contain the MAC address of the machine you want to wake up.  So every other machine on your network will receive the packet and ignore it.

---

## Complex Answer

On an Ethernet LAN packets are *always* sent to hardware (MAC) addresses not IP addresses.  When machine A `192.168.1.2` tries to send a message to machine B `192.168.1.3` it uses [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) to find the mac address associated with `192.168.1.3` and then send the message to that mac address.

Normally ARP works by A broadcasting "who is `192.168.1.3`" and machine B responding "it's me".  But with machine B switched off, machine B cannot respond and doesn't even know it's own IP address.  So ARP cannot work with machine B switched off.

Fortunately Linux will let you statically set the MAC address associated with an IP address and bypass ARP all together.  In your case you would do that on your r-pi custom router:

```
sudo arp -s <ip address> <PC's mac address>
```

Eg:

```
sudo arp -s 192.168.1.3 00:0a:29:10:24:af
```

Now your router (and only your router) knows how to talk to `192.168.1.3` without it being switched on.  As long as WOL has been setup on that machine and it is plugged in correctly you can address the WOL packet to the PCs IP address.

For this to work you do need to be sure that `192.168.1.3` will never be used by another machine.  It's helpful to make sure that your PC always has this IP address, or things will get very confusing.

---

> Question1: How can I assign IP address to eth1 when the device connecting eth1 turns off?

Use `sudo arp -s <ip address> <mac address>` on the machine that wants to talk to it.

> Question2: Should I create virtual bridge to achieve this?

No

Comment: Thank you for good explanation! I tried your answer. Please see updated question. But `SIOCSARP: Network is unreachable` was shown... I googled this error message, I can't find answer...

Comment: @jjjkkkjjj sounds didn't you remember to replace `192.168.1.3` with the actual IP address of your PC?  Home networks vary, yours might not start `192.168.1.x`, other common blocks are `192.168.0.x` and `10.10.10.x` but I can't guess without seeing your actual IPs because there are very many possible configurations.

Comment: I could pass `sudo arp -s 192.168.1.19 **:**:**:**:**:**`. But my PC is still sleeping now. After I sent magic packet from raspi using `wakeonlan` package as test, my PC didn't wake up...